# Cannot capture value selected from Kendo UI drop-down list in Test Studio

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, automated-tests, dropdown, telerik-test-studio

**Drop-down screen shot**

[image: Drop-down screen shot]

I'm having issue selecting from Kendo UI drop-down list. It recorded well, but when I run the test, the mouse stopped at the drop-down without selecting the value from the drop-down. It works when the value I selected is visible from the drop-down (meaning I do not have to scroll-down), but when I select the value which needs to be scrolled down from the list, it is not working. I'm trying to select project name '30' which is not visible in the drop-down (see attached screen shot). 
 I'm running test in IE. The test scripts are:

1. Click 'Span'
2. Wait for '6000' msec
3. Desktop command: HoverOver on StaticProjectSelectorListboxUnorderedList
4. Wait for 3000 msec
5. KendoListBox: select item by text '30'
6. wait for '3000' msec

   It failed at step 5. I'm trying to find 'simulate real click option' from the test step which may resolve the issue, but I cannot find.

   Please help.

Comment: This isn't a kendo-ui issue.  What is your test script tool?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention this was done in test studio. trying to automate the test for Kendo UI based application. But looks like the drop-down is not working when I execute the test after recording the test steps.